# Matching Rows Containing Duplicate Cells

Tags: excel, vba

The thread "Remove Duplicate Cells in a Row" provides what, I believe, is efficient syntax for the stated purpose above (Title). It's beautiful code that I am motivated to run repurposed. However, my slight modifications have ruined the code somehow:

```
    wsR.Range("E1").Value = "Match"
    
    Dim lR As Long
    Dim lC As Long
    Dim k As Long 'row index
    Dim c As Long 'column index
    Dim i As Long
        
    With wsR.UsedRange
        lR = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
        lC = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
    End With
        
    For k = 2 To lR
        For c = 1 To lC
            For i = c + 1 To lC 'change lastCol to c+2 will remove adjacent duplicates only
                If wsR.Cells(k, i) <> "" And wsR.Cells(k, i) = wsR.Cells(k, c) Then
                    wsR.Cells(k, "E") = "Unmatched"
                    Else
                    wsR.Cells(k, "E") = "Matched"
                    
                End If
            Next i
        Next c
    Next k
```

Notice my attempt to insert the string "Matched" into column E for every positive row.

What have I missed?

Comment: Why are you not using `r` anywhere inside the loop? Why are you using `k` and `l`, which are both equal to `0`?

Comment: Corrected typos, @BigBen. I see what you mean. My understanding of this nested loop was it checks each kth row by ith column for a match and then drops the result, "Matched", for positives into the corresponding kth row of Column E. I would have to write this instruction inside the loop as revised in the question but the reference is invalid. What is the best way to structure the syntax inside the loop?

Comment: `.Rows(k, "E") = "Matched"` is not valid syntax. You had it right with `Cells`.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have access to the new dynamic array formulas. This would be extremely easy with `UNIQUE`.

Comment: No luck with Cells either. UNIQUE? I'm all ears, @BigBen ...

Comment: Does your version of Excel support it?

Comment: Version 2013/16.

Answer (score 0):

```
    wsR.Range("E1").Value = "Match"
    
    Dim lR As Long
    Dim lC As Long
    Dim k As Long 'row index
    Dim c As Long 'column index
    Dim i As Long
        
    With wsR.UsedRange
        lR = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
        lC = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
    End With
        
    For k = 2 To lR
        For c = 1 To lC
            For i = c + 1 To lC 'change lastCol to c+2 will remove adjacent duplicates only
                If wsR.Cells(k, i) <> "" And wsR.Cells(k, i) = wsR.Cells(k, c) Then
                    wsR.Cells(k, "E") = "Unmatched"
                    Else
                    wsR.Cells(k, "E") = "Matched"
                    
                End If
            Next i
        Next c
    Next k
```